# How do I change background color of storyboard in xcode 4.6.2

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I am working with storyboards in xcode 4.6.2 I simply want to change the background color of the storyboard. Usually I would think (and according to tutorials) I just go to the inspector on the right and there's a drop down to change the background color. However it's not showing up. Instead I see too areas, "simulated metrics" which shows drop down for size, orientation, status bar, top bar and bottom bar and "view controller" which shows title, initial scene check box layout check box which offers wants full screen, hides bottom bar and resize options and transition and presentation style check boxes.
Any one know why I don't see anything for changing background color etc.. am I missing something here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most probably clicking on the view controller which is showing those properties that can be adjusted in the view controller itself. This can be found out on the left of the storyboard or Interface Builder.

[image: View controller]

A view is not the same as view controller. A view controller manages a set of views, as mentioned in the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Try to click on the view of the view controller and you should be able to modify the background color of the view:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the view under the view controller in the storyboard panel. Then go to the Attributes Inspector. Backgorund is about the 4th item down.